# node/sequelize/node with TS - how to cast to number and cast back to string inside a map with OR operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to do addition of the currency prices which i am getting as an array of objects. But each time i receive this data, currency type can differ between 3 and stays same in the whole array of objects.

My problem here is that when i try to do the addition idk about the key beforehand which key(currency_type) it is. I have tried an approach using map and OR operator.

Here is the controller:

```
  const getHistorycalPrices = async (req: IGetHistorycalPricesRequest, res: IGetHistorycalPricesResponse) => {
    
      try {
        if (!req.query.currency) {
          res.status(400).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Could not get historycal prices",
          });
          return;
        }
    
        // Gets currency column by query from crypto DB table
        const allPrices = await Crypto.findAll({ attributes: [req.query.currency, 'createdAt'], order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']] });
    
        if (!allPrices) {
          res.status(400).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Could not get historycal prices",
          });
          return;
        }
    
        // Get first row from crypto DB table
        const firstRowPrices = await Crypto.findByPk(1);
    
        if (!firstRowPrices) {
          res.status(400).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Could not get first row prices",
          });
          return;
        }
    
        res.status(200).send({
          success: true,
          message: "Successfully retrieved historycal prices",
          data: allPrices.map((price) => ({
            cryptoPrices: (+price.BTCUSD + +firstRowPrices.BTCUSD).toString() ||
                          (+price.ETHUSD + +firstRowPrices.ETHUSD).toString() ||
                          (+price.LTCUSD + +firstRowPrices.LTCUSD).toString(),
            createdAt: price.createdAt.toDateString(),
          })),
        });
        return;
      } catch (e) {
    
        res.status(500).send({
          success: false,
          message: "Server error",
        });
        return;
      }
    };
```

Right now when I'm sending the `data` if it's the first line I'll get -

[image]

But if it's the `ETHUSD` OR the `LTCUSD` I'll get -

[image]

There is a problem with my OR operator in the `allPrices.map` but I can't understand what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Optional chaining operator(?.)**.

```js
allPrices.map((price) => ({
        cryptoPrices: (+price?.BTCUSD + +firstRowPrices?.BTCUSD ||
                      +price?.ETHUSD + +firstRowPrices?.ETHUSD ||
                      +price?.LTCUSD + +firstRowPrices?.LTCUSD).toString(),
        createdAt: price.createdAt.toDateString(),
      })),
    });
```

**Another way**: Instead of OR operator, try using the ternary operator.

```js
allPrices.map((price) => ({
     cryptoPrices:(("BTCUSD" in price)?(+price.BTCUSD + +firstRowPrices.BTCUSD):
                  ("ETHUSD" in price)?(+price.ETHUSD + +firstRowPrices.ETHUSD):
                  (+price.LTCUSD + +firstRowPrices.LTCUSD)).toString(),
     createdAt: price.createdAt.toDateString(),
     })),
});
```